# Asymptotics of $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\,dz$ for large $x$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics

I'm interested in the asymptotics of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\,dz$$
as $x\to\infty$. I expect the results to behave similarly to $e^{x^2}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$. However, I'm not quite sure how to develop the leading asymptotics of the integrals. I first thought that for large $x$, the integral should be dominated by its integral over a small ball around the maximum of the integrand $\frac{e^{2z\log x}}{\Gamma(1+z)}$.

To find this maximum, I computed
$$f'(z)=\left(2\log(x)-\psi^{(0)}(1+z)\right)f(z)$$
with $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ the logarithmic derivative of $\Gamma(z)$. Since $f$ never vanishes, the maximum must occur at $z\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\psi^{(0)}(1+z)=2\log x$. Assuming that we will take $x\to\infty$ as well as the asymptotics $\psi(z)=\log z +O(1/z)$ for large and positive $z$, we seek to solve $2\log x= \log(1+z) +O(1/z)$. Exponentiating, we find that $x^2=1+z+O(1)$. Thus, we have that $\operatorname{arg max} f(z)\sim x^2$ is asymptotically correct for large $x$. Let $z_0=x^2$. We can now rewrite the integral as dominated by
$$\frac{e^{2x^2\log x}}{\Gamma(1+x^2)}\int_{z_0-\epsilon}^{z_0+\epsilon} e^{2(z-z_0)\log x} \frac{\Gamma(1+z_0)}{\Gamma(1+z)}\,dz.$$
However, I'm not sure what size to take $\epsilon$ as a function of $x$. I do know that the expression outside of the integral is asymptotic to
$$(2\pi)^{-1/2} \frac{e^{x^2}}{x}.$$
I'm not sure how to deal with the actual integral though. Input is much appreciated.

Edit: Math Stack Exchange [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608789/asymptotics-of-int-0-infty-fracx2z-gamma1z-dz/4608849#4608849)

Comment: Consider $g(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^t}{\Gamma(t+1)}dt$. You differentiate and then split the integral at 1, you find that $g(x)/e^x$ has bounded derivative.

Comment: Ramanujan observed that $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{2z} }}{{\Gamma (1 + z)}}{\rm d}z}  = {\rm e}^{x^2 }  - \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\exp ( - x^2 {\rm e}^t )}}{{t^2  + \pi ^2 }}{\rm d}t} .
$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$Let $g(x)$ denote your integral. Then
$$g(x)\sim e^{x^2} \tag{1}\label{1} $$
as $x\to\infty$.

*Proof:*
$$g(x)=\int_0^\infty dz\,\frac{x^{2z}}{\Ga(1+z)}. \tag{1.5}\label{1.5} $$
So, for $x>0$,
$$g'(x)=\int_0^\infty dz\,\frac{2zx^{2z-1}}{\Ga(1+z)}
=\int_0^\infty dz\,\frac{2x^{2z-1}}{\Ga(z)} \\ 
=2\int_{-1}^\infty dt\,\frac{x^{2t+1}}{\Ga(1+t)}
=2x\int_{-1}^\infty dz\,\frac{x^{2z}}{\Ga(1+z)}.$$
So (and this is the key), $g$ is a solution of the ODE
$$g'(x)=2xg(x)+h(x),$$
where
$$h(x):=2x\int_{-1}^0 dz\,\frac{x^{2z}}{\Ga(1+z)}.$$
Also, $g(0)=0$. So,
$$g(x)=e^{x^2}G(x), \tag{2}\label{2} $$
where
$$G(x):=\int_0^x du\, e^{-u^2}h(u). \tag{3}\label{3} $$
As $x\to\infty$,
$$G(x)\to\int_0^\infty du\, e^{-u^2}h(u)
=\int_0^\infty du\, e^{-u^2}2u\int_{-1}^0 dz\,\frac{u^{2z}}{\Ga(1+z)} \\ 
=\int_0^\infty dv\, e^{-v}\int_{-1}^0 dz\,\frac{v^z}{\Ga(1+z)}  
=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{dz}{\Ga(1+z)}\int_0^\infty dv\, v^z e^{-v}  \\
=\int_{-1}^0 \frac{dz}{\Ga(1+z)}\,\Ga(1+z)=1.  
$$
Now \eqref{1} follows from \eqref{2}. $\quad\Box$

**Remark:** Note that $-\Ga'(1)$ is Euler's $\gamma>0$. Therefore and because $\Ga$ is log convex on $(0,\infty)$, we see that $\Ga$ is decreasing on $(0,1]$. So, for $x\ge1$ we have
$$h(x)<\frac{2x}{\Ga(1)}\int_{-1}^0 dz\,x^{2z}<2x.$$
So, by \eqref{2}--\eqref{3}, for $x\ge1$ the relative error of the asymptotic approximation \eqref{1} is
$$0<R(x):=\int_x^\infty du\, e^{-u^2}h(u)
<\int_x^\infty du\, e^{-u^2}2u=e^{-x^2},$$
which goes to $0$ very fast as $x\to\infty$.

This bound on the relative error seems hard (if at all possible) to get by the [Laplace method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method)/[Watson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) applied to **the original integral expression \eqref{1.5} of $g(x)$**, which gives an asymptotic expansion in integral powers of $x$.

However, one can apply the Watson lemma to **the expression \eqref{2} of $g(x)$** to get the following asymptotic expansion of the absolute error of approximation \eqref{1}, in integral powers of $\ln x$:
$$E(x):=e^{x^2}-g(x)
=e^{x^2}\int_x^\infty du\, e^{-u^2}h(u)
\sim\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k c_k}{(2\ln x)^{k+1}} \tag{4}\label{4}$$
as $x\to\infty$, where $c_k:=\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\frac1{\Ga(1+z)}\big|_{z=0}$, so that $c_0=1$. $\quad\Box$

---

For an illustration, below are the graphs
$\{(x,g(x)/e^{x^2})\colon0\le x\le 4\}$ (solid black),
$\{(x,E(x)/E_0(x))\colon5\le x\le100\}$ (solid red),
$\{(x,E(x)/E_1(x))\colon5\le x\le100\}$ (solid green), and
$\{(x,E(x)/E_2(x))\colon5\le x\le100\}$ (solid blue), where (cf. \eqref{4})
$E_m(x):=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^k c_k}{(2\ln x)^{k+1}}$:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The saddle point of the integrand is at $z=x^2$ for large $x$, this gives the [saddle point approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent#The_asymptotic_expansion_in_the_case_of_a_single_non-degenerate_saddle_point)
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\,dz\rightarrow \frac{x^{2x^2}}{\Gamma(1+x^2)}.$$
You may then obtain higher order terms by performing the gaussian integral around the saddle point,$^\ast$ which gives a pre-exponential factor $\sqrt{2\pi}\,x$. Substituting also the large-$x$ asymptotics of the $\Gamma$ function, I arrive at
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2z}}{\Gamma(1+z)}\,dz\rightarrow e^{x^2}.$$

The $e^{x^2}$ approximation is already quite good for relatively small values of $x$; see the plot (blue curve = exact, orange curve = approximation):

[image]

---

$^\ast$ <sub>The integrand $e^{F(z)}$ with $F((z)=2z\ln x-\ln\Gamma(1+z)$ is expanded to second order about the saddle point $z_0$, where the first derivative vanishes, $F'(z_0)=0$. For $x\gg 1$ one has $z_0=x^2$ and
$$F(z)\approx2z_0\ln x-\ln\Gamma(1+z_0)-\tfrac{1}{2}x^{-2}(z-z_0)^2.$$
The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{F(z)}\,dz$ then gives the asymptotic approximation $e^{x^2}$.</sub>

Comment: Re: The discriminatory power of graphical comparisons, have you tried plotting $e^{x^2} $ or $x^{-1} e^{x^2} $ just for fun as well?

Comment: Incidentally, I cross posted the question to math.stack.exchange (with the link to the post now in my mathoverflow post), and an answer there finds the asymptotics to be purely $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: What tool do you use for plotting?

Comment: the plots are Mathematica output...

Comment: Based on your Taylor expansion I would expect a prefactor of $\sqrt{2\pi} x$ rather than $\sqrt{2\pi x}$, which should explain the discrepancy with the other answers.

Comment: @TerryTao --- indeed, I corrected the error, thank you for spotting this, the saddle point approximation agrees with the other answers.

Comment: One should not write things such as $f(x)\to g(x)$ (as $x\to\infty$, say). That would be equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=g(x)$. However, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ cannot depend on $x$. Perhaps, you meant $f(x)\approx g(x)$ instead or something more specific, such as $f(x)\sim g(x)$; that should be appropriately specified.

Comment: Also, one should distinguish approximate equalities from exact ones. For instance, you wrote "For $x\gg 1$ one has $z_0=x^2$", whereas here one only may have $z_0\approx x^2$ (and the latter approximation should be specified, unless it is made explicit that here we are only talking about heuristics).