# Necessary and sufficient conditions so that $\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(1+a(k))}\sim\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{\Gamma(1+a(t))}\,dt$ as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, asymptotics

First, some notation. I'll write $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0$. I'll also write $g(x)=\omega(f(x))$ if $f(x)=o(g(x))$, *i.e.* $\limsup_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|=\infty$. I'll say $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ if $f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x))$ for all large enough $x$, *i.e.* $f(x)/g(x)=1+o(1)$ for all large enough $x$.

---

I recently posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437844/when-is-it-true-that-sum-k-ge-0-fracxk-gamma1ak-sim-int-0-infty/437847?noredirect=1#comment1128860_437847) on MathOverflow asking whether
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(1+a(k))}\sim\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{\Gamma(1+a(t))}\,dt\tag{1}\label{1}$$
as $x\to\infty$, given that $a(t)\in\omega\left(\frac{t}{\log t}\right)\cap C^\infty[0,\infty)$ as well as being non-negative and monotonically increasing. The answer given provided the a counter-example. In this question, I am asking about what necessary and sufficient conditions must be placed on the function $a(t)$ so that $(\ref{1})$ holds.

I know this relationships hold true when $a(k):=k$ (see [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608789/asymptotics-of-int-0-infty-fracx2z-gamma1z-dz?noredirect=1#comment9718521_4608789), [[3]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437561/asymptotics-of-int-0-infty-fracx2z-gamma1z-dz-for-large-x/437601#437601)), in which case the series is simply $e^x$, as well as when $a(k):=2k$, in which case the series is $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: "what necessary and sufficient conditions" ... Almost all questions of the form "What is A?" are meaningless -- because "A is A" is always an answer here. Asking such a "what is" question, one should say in what terms the object A is to be described (unless this is naturally and commonly understood). In this case, the terms of a desired description should certainly be provided (even though I suspect this can hardly be done, and therefore a reasonable answer can hardly be provided here.)